# How to state one trait is the equivalent of another generic trait for a given type parameter?

Tags: scala, generics, types, traits

I have a generic trait

```
trait MyTrait[T] {

    def apply(t: T): T

    def compose(e: MyTrait[T]): MyTrait[T]
}
```

And another trait which implements this one for a specific type...

```
trait IntTrait extends MyTrait[Int] {

    override def compose(e: MyTrait[Int]): MyTrait[Int]
}
```

Now, even though this isn't a huge deal, it's mostly a matter of aesthetics; I'd like to be able to say...

```
trait IntTrait extends MyTrait[Int] {

    override def compose(e: IntTrait): IntTrait
}
```

But this breaks the contract of the method from MyTrait because it promises to be defined over *all* MyTrait[Int], whereas IntTrait, for all the compiler knows, is just a proper subset of MyTrait[Int].  So what I'd like to be able to do is basically tell the compiler that IntTrait ***IS*** MyTrait[Int].  In other words, that there are no MyTrait[Int]s that are not IntTraits.

I thought I could acomplish this by

```
trait IntTrait extends MyTrait[Int] {

    type IntTrait = MyTrait[Int]

    override def compose(e: IntTrait): IntTrait
}
```

Which works! ...kind of, but if I try to use this elsewhere like...

```
trait doesStuffWithIntTrait {

    def foo: IntTrait
}
```

Then in the implementation, I get an error like this...

```
Type mismatch, expected: IntTrait, actual: IntTrait#IntTrait
```

Any ideas?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`Type mismatch, expected: IntTrait, actual: IntTrait#IntTrait` (base on the `foo` method)this error means that your `foo` method return type is `IntTrait` class type, but you are returning the **type alias** `IntTrait` type(`IntTrait#IntTrait`).

and for **IntTrait IS MyTrait[Int].** is not real, `IntTrait` is the **subclass** of `MyTrait[Int]`.

for your purpose, maybe you can do it like:

```
  trait MyTrait[T] {
    type K <: MyTrait[T]
    def apply(t: T): T
    def compose(e: K): K
  }
  trait IntTrait extends MyTrait[Int] {
    type K = IntTrait
    override def compose(e: IntTrait): IntTrait
  }
```

Answer (score 1):

> So what I'd like to be able to do is basically tell the compiler that IntTrait IS MyTrait[Int]. In other words, that there are no MyTrait[Int]s that are not IntTraits.

Those are actually two quite different desires. For the first, you do want a type alias, but you have it in wrong scope. Remove `trait IntTrait`, add

```
object MyTrait {
  type IntTrait = MyTrait[Int]
}
```

(if you don't have `object MyTrait` yet) and refer to it as `MyTrait.IntTrait`. You can also put it in the [package object](http://alvinalexander.com/scala/scala-package-objects-how-to-name-location-cookbook-recipe).

For the second, you can't convince the compiler about it, but following @chengpohi's solution (or a similar

```
trait MyTrait[T, K <: MyTrait[T]] {
  def apply(t: T): T
  def compose(e: K): K
}
trait IntTrait extends MyTrait[Int, IntTrait] {
  override def compose(e: IntTrait): IntTrait
}
```

) comes close. By itself, it doesn't stop someone from also declaring `trait IntTrait2 extends MyTrait[Int, IntTrait2]`, but you can make `MyTrait` `sealed`.